# Console Application Error "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Tags: c#

STATIC VOID MAIN GOES HERE

```
        string[] dayNames = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };

        string m = "";

        double average = 0;
        double total = 0;

        int[] bCalories = new int[7];
        int[] lCalories = new int[7];
        int[] dCalories = new int[7];

        int[] dayTotal = new int[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter calories for {0} breakfast: ", dayNames[i]);
            bCalories[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter calories for {0} lunch: ", dayNames[i]);
            lCalories[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter calories for {0} dinner: ", dayNames[i]);
            dCalories[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            dayTotal[i] += bCalories[i];
            dayTotal[i] += lCalories[i];
            dayTotal[i] += dCalories[i];

            total += dayTotal[i];
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        average = total /7;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Day\t\tBreakfast\tLunch\tDinner\tDay Total");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (dayTotal[i] > average)
            {
                 m = "*** Above Average";
            }
            else if(dayTotal[i] <= average)
                 m = "";
```

I only recieve the error Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list", after i add the string m to the writeline below. If i do not have the string m at the end of the statement then the program runs fine, its only when i add it that i get AN ERROR

```
         Console.Write("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n", dayNames[i],
         bCalories[i], lCalories[i], dCalories[i], dayTotal[i] + m);
        }

        Console.Write("Average daily calories: {0}", average);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Stupid mistake!! i used  + m instead of ,m. Thanks for the reply! it works 100% now! feels stupid!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    Console.Write("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n", dayNames[i],
     bCalories[i], lCalories[i], dCalories[i], dayTotal[i] + m);
```

You have 6 specifiers (0 - 5), but only 5 arguments being passed in.  If you change this to only include up to `{4}`, it should work properly:

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", dayNames[i],
     bCalories[i], lCalories[i], dCalories[i], dayTotal[i] + m);
```

I would also recommend using `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Console.Write` with a `\n`.  This makes it obvious that your intending to add a line, which in turn makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based start counting from 0 not 1

Comment: @AndreSmith: `dayTotal[i] + m` is one argument.  Did you mean `dayTotal[i], m`?